# Reading <script> value from html/view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see the code here http://plnkr.co/edit/FqfkcyZSqPkA7JjMMLrb?p=preview

I am embedding a javascript object/value in html, which needs to be read by angular. It reads value in index.html, but not in partial. (`_global_link` is read properly, but not `_global_link_partial`). Is it because `_global_link_partial` not available at `$routeChangeSuccess`, if so which event I need to listen to. I could provide the value as `const` in module definition, or directly in controller etc, but this value is very view specific and better to maintain there.

Thanks.

### error:

```
_global_link Object {link: "abc"} controllers.js:3
ReferenceError: _global_link_partial is not defined
```

### code:

```
function Test1Ctrl($scope) {
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function ($event, current) {
    console.log('_global_link', _global_link);
    console.log('_global_link_partial', _global_link_partial);
  });
}
function Test2Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function ($event, current) {
    console.log('_global_link', _global_link);
    console.log('_global_link_partial', _global_link_partial);  });
}
```

### index.html

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="test1">test1</a>
      <li><a href="test2">test2</a>
    </ul>
        <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<h2>in index.html</h2>
<script>
  _global_link = {link: 'abc'}
</script>
```

### partials (test1, test2)

```
<h2>In test1</h2>

<script>
  _global_link_partial = {link: 'link1'}
</script>

<h2>In test2</h2>

<script>
  _global_link_partial = {link: 'link2'}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I short, you need to include jQuery before angular.js

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
```

Take a look at @igor's answer at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/H4haaMePJU0 :

> long story short: it's because the script tag is special and angular doesn't treat it as such. if you include jquery on this page, the code should work.
>
> When angular detects jquery, it will use it for dom manipulation and jquery is smart enough to treat the script tag as special.

#### Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UhKx8QWGTExLgdQMJuyi?p=preview

I changed your example plunker to latest version of angular.js (1.2.13) and also changed the routes a little.

Comment: +1 tanks for pointing to the correct resource and the working example. still, I wish a better approach as so far I didn't need jquery, and just for this!

Comment: @bsr You try to use the global namespace with inline scripts. well This is definitely a bad practice, I saw people using `ngInit` for such things but I would never throw data on my templates. Just make a resolve on the route to get the data injected into your controllers

Comment: may be you can suggest a better way on what I am doing. say, I need to declare some value specific to a view. If I have 500 pages, I need to declare that many (minimum) in my module. but, if it is only used by that view, then if I include it in the view, the load time improves and easier to maintain. what do u think?